# How can I create an R loop with the code provided below?

Tags: r, loops, raster, hdf

Please, I need help in creating a loop that would do the computation shown in the codes below on a hdflist containing 483 files in R. I have added a link that contains two .hdf files and the shapefiles for trial. The code seems to work just fine for a single .hdf file but I'm still struggling with looping. Thank you

`download files from here`
https://beardatashare.bham.ac.uk/getlink/fi2gNzWbuv5H8Gp7Qg2aemdM/

```
# import .hdf file into R using get_subdatasets to access the subsets in the file`
sub <- get_subdatasets("MOD13Q1.A2020353.h18v08.006.2021003223721.hdf")

# convert red and NIR subsets and save them as raster`
gdalwarp(sub[4], 'red_c.tif')
gdalwarp(sub[5], 'NIR_c.tif')

# import red and NIR raster back into R`
# scale the rater while at it`

r_r=raster('red_c.tif') * 0.0001 
r_N=raster('NIR_c.tif') * 0.0001 

# calculate sigma using (0.5*(NIR+red))`
sigma <- (0.5*(r_N+r_r))

# calculate knr using exp((-(NIR-red)^2)/(2*sigma^2))`
knr <- exp((-(r_N-r_r)^2)/(2*sigma^2))

# calculate kndvi using (1 - knr) / (1 + knr)`
kndvi <- (1 - knr) / (1 + knr)

# import shapefile into R`
shp=readOGR(".", "National_Parks")
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

#change crs of shapefile to crs of one of the rasters`
shp2 <- spTransform(shp, crs(kndvi))

# use extent to crop/clip raster`
## set extent`
e <- extent(910000,980000, 530000, 650000)

## clip using crop function`

crop_kndvi <- crop(kndvi, e)

# mask raster using the shapefile`
kndvi_mask <- mask(crop_kndvi, shp2)
```

And then save kndvi_mask as raster for 483 files

[image: final kndvi raster for just one hdf file analyzed]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can do that with `terra`. `terra` is the replacement for `raster`; it is much faster and more versatile. For example, with `terra` you can skip the `gdalwarp` step.

You can write one big `for-loop`, but I prefer to use functions and then call these in a loop or `lapply`.

Also, instead of your raster-algebra approach, it could be more efficient to wrap the `kndvi` computation into its own function and use it with `lapp`. I think that is a better approach as the code is clearer and it allows you to re-use the `kndvi` function.

```
library(terra)
parks <- vect("National_Parks.shp")
parks <- project(parks, "+proj=sinu +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +R=6371007.181 +units=m")
e <- ext(910000,980000, 530000, 650000)
```

kndvi function to be used by `lapp`

```
kndvi <- function(red, NIR) {
    red <- red * 0.0001 
    NIR <- NIR * 0.0001 
    sigma <- (0.5 * (NIR + red))
    knr <- exp((-(NIR-red)^2)/(2*sigma^2))
    (1 - knr) / (1 + knr)
}
```

Main function. Note that I use `crop` *before* the other functions; that saves a lot of unnecessary processing.

```
fun <- function(f) {
    outf <- gsub(".hdf$", "_processed.tif", f) 
    # if file.exists(outf) return(rast(outf))
    r <- rast(f)[[4:5]]
    # or r <- sds(f)[4:5]
    r <- crop(r, e)
    kn <- lapp(r, kndvi)
    name <- substr(basename(f), 9, 16)
    mask(kn, parks, filename=outf, overwrite=TRUE, names=name)
}
```

Get the filenames and use the function with a loop or with `lapply` as shown by Elia.

```
ff <- list.files(pattern="hdf$", full=TRUE)

x <- list()
for (i in 1:length(ff)) {
    print(ff[i]); flush.console()
    x[[i]] <- fun(ff[i])
}
z <- rast(x)
z

#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 518, 302, 2  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 231.6564, 231.6564  (x, y)
#extent      : 909946.2, 979906.4, 530029.7, 650027.7  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : +proj=sinu +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +R=6371007.181 +units=m +no_defs 
#sources     : MOD13Q1.A2020337.h18v08.006.2020358165204_processed.tif  
#              MOD13Q1.A2020353.h18v08.006.2021003223721_processed.tif  
#names       :     A2020337,     A2020353 
#min values  : 0.0007564131, 0.0028829363 
#max values  :    0.7608207,    0.7303495
```

This takes about 1 second per file on my computer.

Or as a `for-loop` that you asked for:

```
ff <- list.files(pattern="hdf$", full=TRUE)
for (f in ff) {
    print(f); flush.console()
    outf <- gsub(".hdf$", "_processed.tif", f) 
    r <- rast(f)[[4:5]]
    r <- crop(r, e)
    kn <- lapp(r, kndvi)
    name <- substr(basename(f), 9, 16)
    mask(kn, parks, filename=outf, overwrite=TRUE, names=name)
}

outf <- list.files(pattern="_processed.tif$", full=TRUE)
x <- rast(outf)
```

Comment: The processing speed is amazing and it saves a whole of CPU processing memory and time. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your code in a function and then `lapply` over the hdf path. In this way if your loop is too slow it will be easy to parallelize it.
You could try this:

```
library(gdalUtils)
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
#set the directory where you have .hdf files. In my case I downloaded your data in "D:/download"
setwd("D:/download")
#function to save the masked index in your current working directory
#the final files name will depend on the name of the input hdf files
myfun <- function(path){
  name <- basename(tools::file_path_sans_ext(path))
  sub <- get_subdatasets(path)
  gdalwarp(sub[4], paste0(name,'_red_c.tif'))
  gdalwarp(sub[5], paste0(name,'NIR_c.tif'))
  r_r=raster(paste0(name,'_red_c.tif')) * 0.0001 
  r_N=raster(paste0(name,'NIR_c.tif')) * 0.0001 
  
  sigma <- (0.5*(r_N+r_r))
  knr <- exp((-(r_N-r_r)^2)/(2*sigma^2))
  kndvi <- (1 - knr) / (1 + knr)
  crop_kndvi <- crop(kndvi, e)
  kndvi_mask <- mask(crop_kndvi, 
  shp2,filename=paste0(name,"_kndvi_mask.tif"))
}



    #list the hdf file in your current working directory. Thanks to setwd("D:/download") there is no need to specify the path argument of list.files().
   b#however for the for peace of mind:
    hdf <- list.files(path=getwd(),pattern = "hdf",full.names = T)
    #since your shop is always the same you could keep this part out of the function
    shp=readOGR(".", "National_Parks")
    options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    shp2 <- spTransform(shp,  "+proj=sinu +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6371007.181 +b=6371007.181 +units=m
                        +no_defs ")
    e <- extent(910000,980000, 530000, 650000)
    #now run your function across the hdf files path
    lapply(hdf, myfun)
```

in your working directory now you find all the saved if

```
   list.files(pattern = "tif")
[1] "MOD13Q1.A2020337.h18v08.006.2020358165204_kndvi_mask.tif"
[2] "MOD13Q1.A2020337.h18v08.006.2020358165204_red_c.tif"     
[3] "MOD13Q1.A2020337.h18v08.006.2020358165204NIR_c.tif"      
[4] "MOD13Q1.A2020353.h18v08.006.2021003223721_kndvi_mask.tif"
[5] "MOD13Q1.A2020353.h18v08.006.2021003223721_red_c.tif"     
[6] "MOD13Q1.A2020353.h18v08.006.2021003223721NIR_c.tif"
```

With `lapply` on my PC the function run in 45 seconds.
You could easily parallelize `lapply` by replacing it with `sfLapply` from the `snowfall` package, for example. For just 2 files it's not worth it, but if you have hundreds of files you can speed up the process a lot:

```
library(snowfall)

#open cluster with as many node as hdf file
sfInit(parallel=TRUE, cpus=length(hdf))
# Load the required packages inside the cluster
sfLibrary(raster)
sfLibrary(rgdal)
sfLibrary(gdalUtils)
sfExportAll()
system.time(sfLapply(hdf, myfun))
sfStop()
```

with `sfLapply` this function took 20 secs to run. It is a good improvement

Comment: Thank you. I have tried it but I keep getting error messages. Also, I can't seem to find where you applied how the extent "e" was applied to the process.  ```Error in .rasterObjectFromFile(x, band = band, objecttype = "RasterLayer",  : 
  Cannot create a RasterLayer object from this file. (file does not exist)```

Comment: I think it is a problem with the directory and file path, because on my PC with the data you provided via the link all work like a charm. Try to add `setwd("path/to/directory/with/hdf/file")` I edit my answer with this extra line. The code is exactly your code wrapped into a function with the files `path` as an argument, so the `e` was applied in the same manner you applied it (in the line `crop_kndvi <- crop(kndvi, e)`)

Comment: The code works now but after processing a few files, I get this error. ```Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'is.factor': Failure during raster IO
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)```.        Yes, I later noticed you included the extent.

Comment: I also tried using the ```snowfall``` library but after this line ```sfInit(parallel=TRUE, cpus=length(hdf))```, I got the following error message ```Error in file(con, "w") : all connections are in use
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
Error in sfInit(parallel = TRUE, cpus = length(hdf)) : 
  Starting of snow cluster failed! Error in file(con, "w") : all connections are in use
 Error in file(con, "w") : all connections are in use```.

Comment: this error has never happened to me, so I don't think I can help you. It seems that your CPUs are already busy, maybe you are running other operations. For example software like ArcGis do several operations in parallel silently and can use all the workers of your PC

Comment: Yes, I understand what you mean. I'm using a university computer with admin protection. Most operations can't be stopped because they are admin-protected. Thank you for your help @Elia.

Answer (score 0):

```
hdf_files <- list.files("foldername", pattern = ".hdf")

for(f in files) { ... }
```

For the save code, you can use the string "f" to create a name for the file, so they don't save on top of each other.

Comment: It is always a good practice to add `full.name=T` as the argument of `list.files`

Comment: it would be helpful to include specific code in `...` to help answer the question. also the comment of `full.names = TRUE` will really depend on the code in the `for` loop

Comment: Oops, yes, `full.names = TRUE` is always the bit I add after my code has errored. Apologies! Also apologies for the incomplete bit where I put `...`